# Image in banner skews in IPhones and IPads

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, ipad

**Problem:** I have the following css to make the images in the carousel banner responsive:

```
#homepage .carousel .item { 
     height: auto;
} 
/*Carousel images are now responsive*/
#homepage .carousel .item img { 
    min-width: 100% !important; 
    max-width: 100% !important; 
    position: relative !important; 
}
```

This works well for PC, tablets and android devices.

However, for IPads and IPhones, the images skews. It appears it shows the full height of the image rather then adjusting based on the device.

I have the following css styling sheet that handles IPads and IPhones:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px){
    #homepage .carousel .item {
        /*height: auto !important;*/
        margin-top: 154px !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation:landscape){
    #homepage .carousel .item {
        /*height: auto !important;*/
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:961px) and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation:landscape){
    #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
        top: -20px !important;
    }
}
/* Portrait and Landscape iphone*/
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 480px) 
  and (orientation:portrait) { 
    #homepage .carousel .item { height: 150px !important; /*margin-top:71px;*/}
    #homepage .carousel .item img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; }

}
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 480px) 
  and (orientation:landscape) { 
    #homepage .carousel .item { height: 250px !important; }
    #homepage .carousel .item img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; }
}
```

However, the js that I am using appears not be working:

```
function isApple(userAgent){
     var iPhone = userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) !== null;
     var Apple = userAgent.match(/Apple/i) !== null;
     var Mac = userAgent.match(/Mac/i) !== null;
     var iPod = userAgent.match(/iPod/i) !== null;
     var iOS = userAgent.match(/iOS/i) !== null;
          return iPhone || Apple || Mac || iPod || iOS;
        }
        // Use like this...
  if(isApple(navigator.userAgent)){ 
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/MuraBootstrap3/assets/bootstrap/css/iphone.css">');
        }
```

What can I do to make the image not skew for IPhones and IPads?

Thanks

Comment: Try `object-fit`.

Comment: @brandonscript - I have tried this but it does not work for the IPhones or IPads. Thank you for your suggestion though

Comment: What about using a background image and set, and setting `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: @brandonscript - I have also tried that earlier. Not sure what other approach I can do